# Harnessing energy from the moon like from the sun

Tags: science-based, planets, moons, power-sources

So we harness energy from the sun using beams, right? Well what if we were to harness energy coming off the moon the same way? For those long winter months when the sun is rare we could use this to heat our homes, (if the energy is right), but first we would have to make some sort of "Lunar Panels" to harness it. But is this possible? Does the moon give off the correct type of energys for this? If not, is there a different way to harness moons energy? (Besides Tidal Power).

Comment: Keep in mind that light coming off the moon is just reflected sunlight, and has lost a lot of energy in the process.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/can-we-beam-energy-from-the-moon   semi related question that has to do with using the conditions on the moon to create nuclear energy and 'beam it' back to earth.

Comment: It looks like [Physical aspects of the greenhouse effect and global warming](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/67/12/10.1119/1.19109?ver=pdfcov) by Robert S. Knox might be relevant. Randall Munroe used it in [Black Hole Moon](https://what-if.xkcd.com/129/); search for *Knox*.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, except no.  Technically we could get power from the moon via solar (lunar?) panels, but moonlight is far, far weaker.  According to what I've been able to find, it's between a millionth and a three-hundred-thousandth of solar power available for the same area.  Hamsters on wheels would probably provide more effective power.

Now if you use the moonlight to power werewolves on hamster wheels...

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a workaround - but only if your world is advanced enough that local space flight is possible on a regular basis:

Install solar panels - on the moon!

Since the moon suffers from no cloudy days or wintry months, technically you could use solar energy gathered from its surface and then stored in batteries. The batteries would have to be shipped to and from Earth and that could be the foundation for a typical 'super corporation.'

If your world is even more advanced, it could have a novel method of direct energy transmission - but the problems of energy lost in transmission, effects on the Earth's atmosphere and ionosphere, as well as local energy transmissions (radio and internet) would be catastrophic. Then again, if your race is that advanced, it could have better methods on other worlds.

If all else fails, Darth Wedgius' Werewolf Hamster Wheels are worth a shot - if you're that desperate!

Comment: A better way would be to install them on satellites in orbit - less distance to travel

Comment: The energy required for earth to moon transport is far far higher than the energy density of batteries. Using the solar power to create nuclear isotopes or antimatter, then shipping it back to earth could make sense, otherwise use microwave beams.

Answer (score 1):

Well we can theorically **fill the moon surface with mirrors** (well the ~50% of visible moon at least), directed toward Earth and with a slightly parabolic surface in order that each single mirror can focus the light on a particular point of the Earth. If every mirror can alter its orientation according to moon phase then we will have a varying amount of energy to be used on a single point (that can in example use a steam tank to convert the **Moon-laser** into kinetic energy)..

[image: Courtesy of Wikipedia.]

Looks actually more like a weapon than anything really usefull, and as side effect moon will no longer be visible clearly because now instead of reflecting light in each direction is reflecting light only in a specific point of the Earth surface.

The working principle is like current solar plants, but instead of using a central tower, we use Earth:
[image]

I don't really know if that kind of thing would just cut the Earth in 2 or if we need to orient the mirrors towards multiple points instead of only 1, seems much more feasible than moving batteries. Apart the cost of putting there a so big number of mirrors, seems actually even a really viable solution.

Probably there will be night **big events only on full moon nights** (to power up stadium lights and people TVs watching the games).

Comment: As I pointed out in the new thread: this will not work. The only thing that happens is that on 5% of the Earth's surface, you get another Sun. At that distance you cannot focus the Sun tighter than a circle of 1700 km. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/51840/12297

Comment: Well a second sun can still be used with solar panels

Comment: So just build twice as many solar panels on Earth instead. Bouncing the light off the Moon first and then losing 30% in the atmosphere is just a waste of time, money and effort. Or build the solar panels on the Moon — instead of mirrors — use the energy to produce something that requires energy (like metals or fuel or fertilizers or whatever) and ship the goods to Earth.